# Matlab User Input/While Loop

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I'm writing a function in Matlab that prompts the user to select an Instrument (.wav file) to be read in using the `wavread` function.

I'm trying to include some sort of error handling/deal with incorrect inputs from the user.

So far my function looks like this:

```
prompt = 'Select Instrument, Piano: [P], Fork: [F], Violin: [V], Gameboy: [G]';
str = input(prompt,'s');
if isempty(str)
    str = 't';
end

while(str ~= 'P') || (str ~= 'F') || (str ~= 'V') || (str ~= 'G')
    prompt = 'Invalid Selection! Choose, Piano: [P], Fork: [F], Violin: [V], Gameboy: [G]';
    str = input(prompt,'s');
    if isempty(str)
        str = 't';
    elseif (str == 'P') || (str == 'F') || (str == 'V') || (str == 'G')
        break
    end
end
```

If prompted during the while loop, it successfully prompts the user and reads in the `.wav`, but if the user presses `P`,`F`,`V`, or `G` on the first prompt, the while loop is still used and `"Invalid Sel... "` is still displayed...

I'm not sure how I should be implementing this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because you logic is wrong

```
(str ~= 'P') || (str ~= 'F') || (str ~= 'V') || (str ~= 'G')
```

is always true as str is always going to be different from either P, F, V or G. It can't be the same as all of them which is what you are asking.

It should be

```
str ~= 'P' && str ~= 'F' && str ~= 'V' && str ~= 'G'
```

or

```
~(str == 'P' || str == 'F' || str == 'V' || str == 'G')
```

or in sane matlab

```
~any('PFVG' == str)
```

Comment: Oh of course. I feel silly now. Thanks for clearing that up. Problem solved :D
Also `~any('PFVG' == str)` is a really cool line of code, I'm going to use this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

how about using `strcmp`?

```
str = input(prompt,'s');
if isempty(str)
    str = 't';
end

while ~any(strcmp(str,{'P' 'F' 'V' 'G'})) %|| (str ~= 'F') || (str ~= 'V') || (str ~= 'G')
    prompt = 'Invalid Selection! Choose, Piano: [P], Fork: [F], Violin: [V], Gameboy: [G]';
    str = input(prompt,'s');
    if isempty(str)
        str = 't';
    elseif (str == 'P') || (str == 'F') || (str == 'V') || (str == 'G')
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: I've not seen the `strcmp` before. I'm going to have a read up of it now. Thanks for you time :D